# Python timezone from string

Tags: python, string, date, datetime, pytz

I would need your help to convert a list of date such as :
`['4:00 PM','6: 00 AM','2:30 AM']` 
into GMT Time.
I know that I need to convert it to datetime type first, and use 'pytz' library for the time zones.
And I would like something like this
`['9:00 PM GMT','11: 00 AM GMT','7:30 AM GMT']`.thank you

Comment: What is your current code?  Do you know the initial timezone those dates are in?

Comment: initially the time is like '4:00 PM ET' , but it is a string from a excel doc and i found easier to remove all 'ET' because in pytz , i only found EST as timezone

Comment: first of all, your example list only contains times, not dates. to me, it doesn't make much sense to associate a time zone to a time only, without date (think DST...). from your comment, it seems the times originate from time zones other than UTC, e.g. `4:00 PM ET` could mean US/eastern, which is UTC-4 if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: I did found out how , the time and the timezone were in separated column inside the csv file . i join them together and convert it.